Pandas subtract 1 from row value based on condition
I'm having a problem using pandas and I really haven't been able to find a solution to it despite the fact that it's probably a fairly common task.
I have a dataframe that has 3 columns,  year as integer, a quarter as text, and a value.
The problem I have is that the year column is based on a report date and the Q4 quarter is always one year ahead.  All I want to do is subtract 1 from the year where quarter = "Q4".
Current dataframe
YEAR  QUARTER  VALUE
2021  Q1       1
2021  Q2       1
2021  Q3       1
2022  Q4       1
2022  Q1       1
2022  Q2       1
2022  Q3       1
2023  Q4       1
Transformed Dataframe
YEAR  QUARTER  VALUE
2021  Q1       1
2021  Q2       1
2021  Q3       1
2021  Q4       1
2022  Q1       1
2022  Q2       1
2022  Q3       1
2022  Q4       1
I'm sure this is a pretty basic thing but I've had no luck finding the proper way to do it.
If possible, I would like to use .loc as all of my other data transformations use it and I would like to be consistant, if not then whatever works.
Thanks.

One option: df.loc[df['QUARTER'].eq('Q4'), 'YEAR'] -= 1

Thank you so much @mozway.
I was trying df.loc[df['QUARTER'].eq('Q4'), 'YEAR'] = df["YEAR"] - 1 but it just wasn't working.

It should have worked if the indices are unique. Alternatively, m = df['QUARTER'].eq('Q4') ; df.loc[m, 'YEAR'] = df.loc[m, 'YEAR']-1.
